# How to run SelekTOR on Elementary OS?

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install and run SelekTOR according to [this article](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/09/selektor-tor-gui-with-country-exit-node.html). Installation is fine, but when I am trying to run it, nothing happens. Here is console output:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

(java:31665): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(java:31665): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(java:31665): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(java:31665): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(java:31665): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.awt.TrayIcon.<init>(TrayIcon.java:144)
    at java.awt.TrayIcon.<init>(TrayIcon.java:168)
    at java.awt.TrayIcon.<init>(TrayIcon.java:197)
    at java.awt.TrayIcon.<init>(TrayIcon.java:227)
    at lib.SwingTrayIcon.<init>(SwingTrayIcon.java:65)
    at client.SelekTOR.<init>(SelekTOR.java:213)
    at SelekTOR$1.run(SelekTOR.java:42)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

On KDE everything was working fine, but not on Elementary OS.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Do you know if this application is using a compiled-in version of Java, or does it pull in something like OpenJDK?

Comment: @LewisGoddard I really don't know. The command for this process in `ps aux` is `java -Xms32m -Xmx64m -jar SelekTOR.jar`, maybe this will help

Comment: Hm, that looks like it's relying on whatever is supplying the `java` command on your machine. Maybe try using this [WebUpd8 Article](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html) to install the latest version.

Comment: @LewisGoddard I installed my Java version from this repo

Comment: Ah, it appears that `java.awt.TrayIcon` may actually require an _older_ version of Java. Try version 7, if not version 6.

Comment: @LewisGoddard Oracle Java 6 crashes with this message: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: SelekTOR : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`, will try to install Java 7 now

Comment: @LewisGoddard aaaand Java 7 crashes with the same message as Java 8

Comment: Ah, it seems like they are aware of the issue. "Tray icon is disabled on the Gnome 3 desktop due to legacy tray support on that desktop being in a very poor state and completely dysfunctional when it comes to Java tray icon support." - http://www.dazzleships.net/selektor-for-linux/ Unfortunately this seems to be a hardcoded list instead of a version check, as elementary isn't recognized as being Gtk3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SelekTOR developer here, you should pretty much always use the SelekTOR download from the official website http://www.dazzleships.net.

As noted by LewisGoddard trayicon support is disabled on Gnome based systems it does use a hardcoded desktop detection list but if this list fails it falls back to actually trying to load the trayicon and if that fails it disables the trayicon support automatically so it should start up fine.

I just checked the latest release 3.13.38 against the latest ElementaryOS and it works fine with Chromium and Firefox. Do not use Midori as it does not have the required PAC proxying support.

My recommendation for SelekTOR on Elementary would be to pin it to the dock and in SelekTOR preferences ensure "Minimise instead of Exit on close" is checked.
You can also set "Minimise on startup" if you intend to use auto startup.

Regards

Alistair Neil

SelekTOR Maintainer

Answer (score 1):

Updating SelekTOR to the latest version solved the problem.
P.S. That's strange that .deb from site is version 3.13-38, though it installs SelekTOR version 3.13.18

Answer (score -1):

A lot of graphical Java applications are based on Swing, which relies on the pixbuf rendering engine.

Unfortunately pixbuf is not installed in elementary OS by default. Install pixbuf and your errors should be gone:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf
```

Comment: nope, they didn't

Comment: Gtk2 engines aren't going to help much in a Gtk3 environment. PixBuf warning can be safely ignored, and are even present in some default apps.