# Problems Installing DraftSight in Elementary OS Loki 0.4

Tags: release-loki, software-installation, pantheon

DraftSight is an AutoCAD look-alike that has worked well for me in both Windows and MAC OS.  I am trying to switch over to Linux and tried to install it on my Loki 0.4 machine.

I found some advice on this page:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/466522/how-to-install-draftsight-on-ubuntu-64bits

I ran this command in Terminal:
sudo apt-get install libuuid1:i386 libice6:i386 libsm6:i386 libxt6:i386 libaudio2:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 libcanberra-gtk0:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386

Draftsight started but after the usual registration window it flashed a white window and then disappeared.

I don't recall where I found the suggestion to run this command:
cd /opt/dassault-systemes/DraftSight/Linux/

and then this:
./DraftSight

I then got this error message:
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

(DraftSight:2826): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(DraftSight:2826): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(DraftSight:2826): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(DraftSight:2826): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
Could not parse stylesheet of object 0x2ee0df0
Could not parse stylesheet of object 0x2ee0df0

A link on this page: [gtk2 apps not working in elementary](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1368/gtk2-apps-not-working-in-elementary)

Sent me here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1472836

But the bug does not seem to be fixed, at least as far as DraftSight is concerned.

I just recently ran updates and upgrades for my Elementary OS and I downloaded the current version of DraftSight.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just installed it on Loki, and it works perfectly fine. Installed it using Eddy. I got these errors too but it does not affect Draftsight starting and working normally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=gtk2` before the `draftsight` command.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to install pixmap with Synaptic